# Wordpress: Contact Form 7 - Time stamp variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a question regarding variables in Contact Form 7.

I need to get a unique ID such as time stamp, form id or similar when a user submits my contact form at https://hotpaper.dk/kontakt. The ID/$variabel is a requirement used to track a affiliate partner’s successful leads.

The ID should be set as a variabel in the tracking code URL where it says “VARIABEL”:

```
<…s.com/dk/leadtrack.php?programid=6417&type=lead&uiv=VARIABEL” width=0 height=0 style=”display:none”>
```

So it would be something like:

```
<…s.com/dk/leadtrack.php?programid=6417&type=lead&uiv=$time” width=0 height=0 style=”display:none”>
```

Can anyone guide me how to extract that variabel from CF7?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards
Henrik

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. How would a _random_ value allow to track leads? _“The ID should be set as a variabel in the tracking code URL”_ - and how does this tracking URL get called in the first place?

Comment: Where does the URL come from, or where are you trying to read it from? Is that submitted along with the form?

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear. 

I think that the random id is used to check who in their affiliate network has given the lead. I am not sure, but that's how they want it.

The tracking code is called by Google Tag Manager. When the contact form is submitted, the page redirects to a thank you page which fires the tag with the tracking URL. The thank you page is: https://hotpaper.dk/tak/

Comment: Can you explain the complete flow in detail and exactly which value (field in the form) do you want to use as the random id?

Comment: When a user completes the contact form it should freeze a variable like a time stamp. I can not use any variables from the form fields as it is now because the inputs aren't unique (the phone number, email and so on can be used again). So my question is how do I get the system to create a time stamp variable that can be set as a variabel in the tracking code URL?

I hope it make sense.